# Fitting image to ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to fit an image completely in a imageview. I have tried scaletype("fitXY") and also centercrop. But I always notice that the imageview is not completely filled. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPt4x.png)

Is there something of a border I have to adjust or something the like? 
My goal is to make a maze out of these rectangles.

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/zwarte_balk"
    android:src="@mipmap/zwarte_balk"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Please, share some code. It's a bit hard to find out what's wrong with just the info you gave.

Comment: Change your scaletype to Center

Comment: @Ahmed Center did not work. It only made image become smaller in the imageview.

Comment: Change the location of your image from the `mipmap` folder to the `drawable` folder.

Comment: Have you tried centercrop?

Comment: Changed it to drawable. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

To fix that, change your image from the `mipmap` folder to the `drawable` folder (or `drawable-nodpi`).

The first folder is usually used for launcher icons, or the mipmap API from the `Bitmap` class.

As per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html):

> Using a mipmap as the source for your bitmap or drawable is a simple
>   way to provide a quality image and various image scales, which can be
>   particularly useful if you expect your image to be scaled during an
>   animation.